# A spectral sequence for computing cohomology of a space from that of its strata

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, cohomology

Let $X$ be a smooth complex variety (not necessarily compact) and let $D$ be a normal crossings divisors with components $D_1$, $D_2$, ..., $D_N$. For a set of indices $I$, let $D_I = \bigcap_{i \in I} D_i$ and let $D^{\circ}_I = D_I \setminus \bigcup_{J \supsetneq I} D_J$. I would like to compute $H^{\ast}(X)$ in the case that I know all of the $H^{\ast}(D_I^{\circ})$.

It seems to me that there should be a spectral sequence whose first page is $\bigoplus_{\#(I)=p} H^{q-p}(D^{\circ}_I)$. If $I' \supset I$ with $\#(I') = \#(I)+1=p+1$, then the map $H^{q-p}(D^{\circ}_{I}) \to H^{q-(p+1)}(D^{\circ}_{I'})$ would given by the Gysin map (up to standard sign issues).

Does this sequence have a name, or is it a special case of something which has a name? Where can I read about it?

Comment: I don't have the book with me now, but there is something similar at the beginning of David Morrison's article on the Clemens-Schmid sequence in "Topics in Transcendental Algebraic Geometry".  Maybe another MO user has more details . . .

Comment: here is that reference, if it helps. http://math.ucsb.edu/~drm/papers/clemens-schmid.pdf

Comment: Possibly related: http://arxiv.org/abs/1603.01137

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks! Eqn (3) is basically what I want, I just need to think about Poincare duality and wish Petersen said more about it.

Comment: Applying Poincare duality $H^d_c(X) \cong H^{\dim X-d}(X)$ and dualizing all the maps turns Petersens $E_1$ page (3) into mine (after some reindexing). I'd still love references more detailed than Petersen's offhand reference. (In particular, I want to make sure it is compatible with mixed Hodge structure.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let $X = T_n \supset T_{n-1} \supset \cdots \supset T_{-1} = \varnothing$ be a topological space filtered by closed subspaces, where for simplicity I assumed the filtration bounded. Then there is a spectral sequence
$$ E_1^{pq} = H^{p+q}_c(T_p \setminus T_{p-1}) \implies H^{p+q}_c(X).$$
(Some mild point-set assumptions are required for this and what follows to be true, but let me disregard that.) As you noted in a comment, this gives the spectral sequence you want by Poincaré duality.

Usually, the spectral sequence of a filtered space is written in terms of ordinary cohomology rather than cohomology with compact support. One reason is that the compactly suppported spectral sequence is a special case of the usual one. Recall that if $U \subset \overline U$ is any compactification of a space $U$, then $H^\bullet_c(U) = H^\bullet(\overline U, \partial U)$, where $\partial U = \overline U \setminus U$. So if we choose an arbitrary compactification $X \subset \overline X$ and let $\overline T_p$ be the closure of $T_p$ in $\overline X$, then we get a filtration 
$$\overline X = \overline T_n \cup \partial X \supset \overline T_{n-1} \cup \partial X \supset \overline T_{n-2} \cup \partial X \supset \cdots \supset \overline T_{-1} \cup \partial X = \partial X.$$

Now the usual spectral sequence of a filtration  reads
$$ E_1^{pq} = H^{p+q}(\overline T_p \cup \partial X,\overline T_{p-1}\cup \partial X) = H^{p+q}(\overline T_p,\overline T_{p-1})  \implies H^{p+q}(\overline X, \partial X),$$
and this is the spectral sequence we wanted.

(Often one chooses $\overline X$ and $\overline T_p$ to be the one-point compactification of $X$ resp. $T_p$, and then the above is just the spectral sequence for the reduced cohomology a filtered *based* space. But allowing yourself to use any compactification is useful in the algebraic setting, which you are interested in.)

Here's an alternative "sheafy" derivation of the spectral sequence. The constant sheaf $\mathbf Z_X$ is filtered:
$$\mathbf Z_X = \mathbf Z_{T_n} \supset \mathbf Z_{T_{n-1}} \supset \cdots \supset \mathbf Z_{T_{-1}} = 0$$ where I denote by $\mathbf Z_A$ the pushforward of the constant sheaf on the subspace $A$. The successive quotients in the associated graded for this filtration are of the form ${j_n}_!\mathbf Z$, where $j_n$ is the locally closed inclusion of $T_n \setminus T_{n-1}$. Taking compactly supported cohomology of this filtered object gives rise to a spectral sequence which is exactly the one we want. A useful reference for making sense of this is the section about filtered objects and spectral sequences in Lurie's "Stable $\infty$-categories" (Chapter 1 of Higher Algebra).

To answer a question you made in the comments, the spectral sequence of a filtered space is indeed compatible with mixed Hodge structure, when $X$ is an algebraic variety filtered by closed subvarieties. So the one you consider (by Poincaré duality) is compatible up to Tate twist. I don't know what is the canonical reference for this fact, but Sections 3 and 4 of Arapura's "The Leray spectral sequence is motivic" proves rather generally that the spectral sequence of a filtered algebraic variety is compatible with all kinds of extra "motivic" structure.

Comment: Thanks! Lemma 3.8 in Arapura is particularly close to what I want; I'll definitely be able to piece together the rest now.

Comment: Do you know, if there is a similiar Spectral Sequence for Intersection Cohomology?

Comment: Yes, it works in intersection cohomology as well, sort of. You can use the sheafy approach but plug in $\mathrm{IC}_X$ instead of $\mathbf Z_X$. The only issue is that if $i$ is the inclusion of a closed subspace $A$ then $i^\ast \mathrm{IC}_X$ is not in general equal to the intersection complex on $A$ (even with a degree shift), unlike $i^\ast \mathbf Z_X = \mathbf Z_A$. So you need to compute the sheaves $i^\ast \mathrm{IC}_X$ in order to get a spectral sequence. One example of such a calculation is Section 3.4 of Beilinson-Ginzburg-Soergel "Koszul duality patterns in representation theory".

Comment: What definition of compactification you need to adopt in order to have $H_c^\bullet(U) = H^\bullet(\bar U, \partial U)$?. And how would one prove this? I have seen this result for singular cohomology using the one-point compactification, but I don't know the general result.